# express.js - How do I serve different static folders on production and development separately?

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

So basically I want to serve the `../client` directory on development, where it has the current files being edited. During production, however, I have a folder `../client/dist` that I want to serve. How do I achieve this?

I tried making a simple `if` condition but for some reason it does not seem to work and it doesn't load the files.

```
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
if (production) {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client/dist'))
} else {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client'))
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Share the `if` condition.

Comment: @Evert I have added the condition I used.

Comment: Are you sure that u use the correct `NODE_ENV` on production?

Comment: @alexmac Yes, but with this code, it doesn't even load in development mode. The static files never get served.

Answer (score 1):

Use `path.join(__dirname, '../client')`.

This will handle the `/` required when joining strings. Refer documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's definitely going wrong is that `__dirname` doesn't end in a slash, resulting in this. You will need an extra slash before `..` to get a valid path.

Comment: I used `path.join`, and then checked what the absolute path was, and it was correct. Yet, when it is in the if condition, it is not working properly.

Comment: @ICanKindOfCode `path.join()` is not in your sample code. We can't help you debug your problem if you don't share us what you actually tried.

Comment: I used the code after someone suggested it in the answers. I used `path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')` and the same for the development folder except with `path.join(__dirname, '../client')`.

Comment: @ICanKindOfCode then update your question with your new source. Maybe it has a new error.